# Getting elements of a div from another page (PHP)

Tags: php, string, html, file-get-contents

So I have page one:

```
<div id="div1">This is text one</div>

<div id="div2">This is text two</div>

<div id="div3">This is text three</div>
```

Now I want to get the elements of div one, that it will return `This is text one`, how can I do that?

Comment: so, you just want to grab text inside of div1 from another page using php?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use DOMDocument in PHP:

```
<?php

$doc = new DomDocument;

// We need to validate our document before refering to the id
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
$doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents('http://google.com/bla.php'));

var_dump($doc->getElementById('div1'));

?>
```

Comment: What about if the content of 'div1' is originally empty and is loaded by javascript ?

Comment: @teuneboon what if the webpage is dynamically generated by the javascript? How can we get in such case?

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = file_get_contents($url);
if (preg_match('/<div id="div1">([^<]*)<\/div>/', $string, $matches) > 0) {
    echo $matches[1]; //This is text one
}
```

Comment: Regular expressions for parsing html is strongly discouraged. You can use DomDocument for that

Comment: DomDocument is not working for me, this script saved my hours of time! I have voted for this user for sharing a very useful snippet with us, thank you!