# fetch data from a website

Tags: php, cakephp, curl

I am developing an application and I need to fetch of data from another source / website. I did google and tested a few options like file_get_contents / Curl. Its clear that curl is much faster compared to file_get_contents.

Now, What I need to fetch is a certain list of contents, like a list of items inside a div. I would like to ignore the HEAD info/scripts/css etc. Just need to fetch the data and style it in my own theme.

Please tell me the best method / function to get contents and style the output. If you can spare sometime and write a basic code it will be really helpful...

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe you'll find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045598/getting-elements-of-a-div-from-another-page-php :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an HTML Parser. I use **Simple HTML DOM PARSER** : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ and it's great. Also has a great documentation. It gives this example in its homepage:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

A *way* you could do this is use `file_get_contents`.

Example:

`$fileHTML = file_get_contents('http://www.google.ca');`
`$title = substr($fileHTML,strpos($fileHTML,'<title>') + 7,strpos($fileHTML,'</title>') - (strpos($fileHTML,'<title>') + 7));`
The + 7 so it will goto the end of <title>
`echo $title;`
This should display the title of the Google website.

The way this could work is by grabbing ID's, because in proper website everything the has an id is unique.

Comment: "everything the has an id is unique." That's not always the case. Use a DOM parser