# php parse content for input->name value

Tags: php, parsing

I'm trying to parse html content, for the value stored in the name tag.

My current try looks like the following:

```
function getAuthToken(){
    $html = file_get_contents('url');
    $values = array();

    foreach($html->find('input') as $element)
    {
        $values[$element->name] = $element->value;
    }

    print_r($values);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you try DomDocument? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5045619/4802649

Comment: as far as I know `file_get_contents` returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

$html in your code is not an object its a string (the results of file_get_contents).

$object->name is a class object

$array[key] is an array element

Neither of these in your code will do what you want to achieve with the result of file_get_contents because your $html var is a string, you need to do some string parsing to get the desired results.

You can check that with:

```
echo gettype($html);
```

You can also just echo out $html to find out what the string looks like to give you a better idea of what you are working with, for instance, is there a common character that you can explode the sting with an so getting an array to work with within your foreach.

example:

```
$newarray = explode('&', $html);

foreach ($newarray as $key => $value) {
 //do your thing
}
```