# How to get text within td element from remote webpage via PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, cross-domain

I have a temperature monitor set up, and I would like to use some of the data for other things (cron jobs, etc). The data from the sensor can be accessed from our local network (192.168.123.123). The element in question is:

```
<td id="1E5410ECC9D90FC3-entity-0-measurement-0" class="">69.08</td>
<!-- I NEED THE 69.08 -->
```

I can't do it via ajax since I get the Allow-Access-Origin error (CORS).

I tried this:

```
$url = 'http://192.168.123.123';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first = explode( '<div id="1E5410ECC9D90FC3-entity-0-measurement-0">' , $content );
$second = explode("</div>" , $first[0] );

echo $second[0];
```

but I got this:

```
��UMS�0��+��$���94С�2����؋-�%#Ʉ�뻲���Bۓ%����ݷr��m4�yyF*_+ry���ӈP������S��|��&�ȵ�2���}��V�7ǜO��dz�[�� (�!�_2��$�/�p/ g�=B� D����<��1�#�=h���J�˨�'��I^ ��g7��=�=��^�0��ϔ����p�Q��L��I�%TF�Q�)    ������;c��o$��a����g��mWr�ܹ��;�(��bE��O�i� ��y�҉)f=�6=�,2� �#I��s����>����kNƕt/W2^��@ Xp�3^݅$ѵ��T U�ʲ�@f��db�ԁ%��b�`G|��D�{sι1�� ]#2ZH�(1;&�h8��^0er��3���D�Q�5B�u� ^!5X:�{a U\:߰0�~Ɍ�3+S�^1��qB:�g����C>�.�P~n��$\֢D����%J+�b�ELc�Gq���K �]��xV��j�[���Ԧ��nAɍ��<�ZT@���zc�Q(f܁�(~�^�ZKwk:8�·n>��(=�"aB)�Fl5�b]/�_�$���_��ɴ��9�H}��B    [#�V�ԅp��r�g�A�j���2����Ju*������{�bY�,O4�����M��B�#�e���,�   ��_֔���o����
```

How can I properly get the 'td' text within the specific div id?

Comment: check your page encoding and PHP encoding.

Comment: Check the content first, before exploding `echo $content = file_get_contents($url);`

Comment: else there is a library phpQuery to use selector like jquery and parse HTML.

Comment: @Rohit.007 If I do that, it still shows the gibberish at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve data from `<td id="1E5410ECC9D90FC3-entity-0-measurement-0" class="">` not `<div id="1E5410ECC9D90FC3-entity-0-measurement-0">`, so not from a `<div>`, so just change it into:

```
$url = 'http://192.168.123.123';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first = explode( '<td id="1E5410ECC9D90FC3-entity-0-measurement-0">' , $content );
$second = explode("</td>" , $first[0] );

echo $second[0];
```

Or am I crazy?

Comment: Sorry about that. You're correct. I still get the gibberish shown above in my question, though.

Comment: No worries, perhaps this could be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045598/getting-elements-of-a-div-from-another-page-php

Comment: Tried that too. Got PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Invalid char in CDATA 0x8 in Entity, line: 1

Comment: that's probably because of a missing/invalid doctype declaration of the file you're trying to get content from

Comment: I discovered this temp monitor system has an API, and I can access everything via JSON. Gonna look into how to do that now, but I'll leave this in case someone else decides to answer and someone needs to know how to do it the original way that was asked.

Comment: If all fails you can also look into https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

I suggest using php's curl library to manage and configure your web request/response.
Using this mechanism allows you to better manage/control encoding, compression and encryption.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

```
// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.123.123");        

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Step 2:

Let's extract the details out of the returned response string from the web server. I suggest PHP's PCRE function preg_match to extract the needed data.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php

```
// Looking for <td id="1E5410ECC9D90FC3-entity-0-measurement-0" class="">69.08</td>
$pattern = '/id="1E5410ECC9D90FC3-entity-0-measurement-0".*>([\d]{1,2}?\.[\d]{1,2})<\//';

// run the regex match and collect the hit
preg_match($pattern, $output, $matches);

// print_r of the array
/*
Array
(
    [0] => id="1E5410ECC9D90FC3-entity-0-measurement-0" class="">69.08</
    [1] => 69.08
)
*/

// Print out the result to check
echo $matches[1];
```