# php replace id element content in string

Tags: php

a bit stuck, is it possible to use PHP to update/change html element contents.
So replace only 'Hello World' in the string below based off the the id name.

```
$html = '<h1 id="item" class="abc" data="efg">Hello World</h1>';
```

Perhaps using preg_replace, just want to leave all other content in there, eg. class, data, etc.

```
$html = preg_replace('<h1 id="item">????</h1>', 'New Content', $html);
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify html attribute with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127142/modify-html-attribute-with-php)

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55693439/how-to-remove-a-div-with-a-certain-id-from-an-external-html-file-with-php?

Comment: `<h1 id="item">` != `<h1 id="item" class="abc"` you also should not use regex to parse HTML. Use a parser.

Answer (score 2):

```
May be below code will help 

$html = '<h1 id="item" class="abc" data="efg">Hello World</h1>';
$elementId = "item";
$newString = "Replace World";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$belement = $dom->getElementById("$elementId");
$oldString = $belement->nodeValue;


$newHTML = str_replace("$oldString","$newString","$html");
echo $newHTML;


Note: Please change $elementId and $newString with original values
```